# Weak power set - what strength may it have?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

In The Consistency of Classical Set Theory Relative to a Set Theory with Intuitionistic Logic in THE JOURNAL OF SYMBOLIC LOGIC Volume 38, Number 2, June 1973 page 316 Harvey Friedman's axiom 8* $Weak \ Power \ Set$ is:

$(\forall a)(\exists x)(\forall y)(\exists z\in x)(z=y\cap a)$

What do we know about weak power set? I am curious about what if anything weak power set can do when added to $KP\omega$ or $ZF-Power \ Set$.

Comment: what does $E$ mean? Possibly you mean $\exists$

Comment: I believe in presence of extensionality and some weak separation ($KP\omega$ should have enough) this axiom is equivalent to full power set.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Yes, I edited

Comment: @Wojowu It would be interesting if that could be whown

Comment: @ I think if you add this to ZF - Power, then you recover full ZF.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar OK

Comment: Of course I'm speaking about classical ZF. But with intuitionistic logic, I don't know.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Friedman showed that a weaker intuitionistic theory interprets , but that is a different situation. I don't at this point believe that  can be recovered in the sense that the power set axiom is a theorem of −+; but I may change my mind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question on request from the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asserted set $x$ is just a set that contains all overlap sets between the set $a$ and any set, among its elements. Weak Power as written above is simply:

$(\forall a)(\exists x)(\forall y)(a \cap y\in x) $

Now in classical ZF all subsets of $a$ are overlaps with $a$, i.e. $z \subseteq a \to z \cap a=z$, so all of them would be included in the weak power of $a$ (just substitute each subset $z$ of $a$ instead of $y$ in the above formula), then by separation one can easily recover full $P(a)$ by separating on the weak power of $a$ using the property of being a subset of $a$.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Friedman in the cited article seems to work in set theory without extensionality. Without it it makes no sense to write $a\cap y$, as there may not be a unique set satisfying its defining property. If you wish to also work in a theory without extensionality (which I'm not sure is the case), you should say so explicitly in your question.

Comment: @Wojowu Extensionality is part of $KP\omega$ and $ZF-Power+Weak Power$, so I already made clear that I presuppose extensionality in the cases I expressed interest in.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal In that case, what is unconvincing about this answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Perhaps it is not unconvincing. It is getting late here, so let me see what I think tomorrow.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal To clarify, what logic are you working in - e.g. does "$KP\omega$" mean $KP\omega$ in classical or intuitionsitc logic?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I presuppose classical logic

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar There are some problems with your rendering of the Weak Power Set Axiom.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal What problems? The sentence $(\forall a)(\exists x)(\forall y)(\exists z\in x)(z = y\cap a)$ is tautologically equivalent to the sentence $(\forall a)(\exists x)(\forall y) (y\cap a\in x)$.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman Sorry, you are right.

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar Thanks, I am convinced.